# Which design pattern for dispayling custom editors according to objects instance?

Tags: java, design-patterns, strategy-pattern, visitor-pattern

I have several objects that all extend a `Shape` basic class. For every object I want to display a different object `editor`, as eg a `Line` has different properties to edit than a `Rectangle`.

```
class Shape;
class Line extends Shape;
class Rectangle extends Shape;

List<Shape> shapes;

void onEditEvent(Shape shape) {
    new ShapeEditorPopup(shape);
    //how to avoid instanceof checks here
}
```

For every implementation of `Shape` there is only one single `Editor` implementation.
What pattern can I use here to: show the right editor for a shape according to the shapes implementation type (`instanceof`)?

I do not want the `Shapes` (domain model) themself to know which the right editor is.

`StrategyPattern` cannot be used here as in `onEditEvent()` it would have to be known which implementation the shape is of, and pass strategy accordingly.

`VisitorPattern` cannot be used here as I would have the `Shapes` implement some kind of `interface Visitable` which would force them to implement a `edit(IEditorVisitor)` method, and by this pollute the domain model with information about how it will be displayed in UI.

What else can I do here?

**Update:**

Example of how I'd to the Visitor Pattern (though I don't like it as I have to "pollute" the domain model with things like `edit(editor)` methods. I'd like to avoid this.

```
interface Editable {
    public void edit(IEditor editor);
}

public interface IEditor {
    public void edit(Shape shape);
}


class Line extends Shape implements Editable {  
    @Override
    public void edit(IEditor editor) {
        editor.edit(this);
    }
}

class EditorImpl implements IEditor {
    void edit(Line line) {
        //show the line editor
    }
    void edit(Rectangle rect) {
        //shwo the rectangle editor
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> VisitorPattern cannot be used here as I would have the Shapes implement some kind of interface Visitable which would force them to implement a edit(IEditorVisitor) method, and by this pollute the domain model with information about how it will be displayed in UI.

Well, no it doesn't have to give the domain model information about how it is displayed or edited.  It need only give the domain  model knowledge that it is visited.

Just don't name your visitor interface `IEditorVisitor` and don't name the `IVisitable` method `edit`.

Visitor is very much suited to this sort of problem.

I would do it more like:

```
public interface IVisitableShape {
    void accept(IShapeVisitor v);
}

public interface IShapeVisitor {
    void visit(Line line);
    void visit(Rectangle rectangle);
}

public class Line extends Shape implements IVisitableShape {

    @Override
    public void accept(IShapeVisitor v) {
        v.visit(this);
    }
}

public class EditorImpl implements IShapeVisitor {
    public void visit(Line line) {
        //show the line editor
    }
    public void visit(Rectangle rect) {
        //show the rectangle editor
    }
}
```

Note that this is essentially equivalent to your implementation sketch, only changing names, so that the function of editing is only in the editor.

The function names `accept` and `visit` are commonly used in descriptions of this pattern, and reflect the pattern.  They can of course be changed, but I don't see the need, and it's certainly better to keep them from being explicitly tied to the editing function.

Comment: Well, naming the methods other then `edit` makes less sense if they are actually for *editing* the objects. Anyhow, I updated my answer. Is that what you would suggest? Still I'm not that happy with it as I have to provide a edit delegate in all of my domain objects...

Comment: You give the concrete implementation of the visitor a function-specific name.  And you can make other visitors that are for functions other than editing the object.

Comment: Thanks for the full example @Don. I recognize that I did not fully understand the visitor pattern so far, as I was not aware that only the VisitorImpl matters and the rest is kind of a fixed pattern to be applied everytime.